# How to set Struts2 Property as Parameter of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, java, struts2, ognl

I want to use the JavaScript method `myJSFunction` in the following way:

```html
<button onclick="myJSFunction('<s:property value="myJavaModel.myJavaMethod(<s:property value="myStuff"/>)" />')">Finalize</button>
```

The JavaScript method need a parameter, which is based on a Javaclass´s method. The method without using a parameter could be called. But this Java Method needs a value from a Struts2 action class. The value is still available in this context, but how can I pass this property value as a parameter in the Java method. The syntax is wrong.

Comment: What happens when you remove nested `<s:property>` tag and just use `myStuff`?

Comment: That is the answer Aleksandr! Thanks !

Comment: Using legal JSP is often the first step.

Comment: @Marwief: You are welcome. See a full answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot nest tags like that, and you don't need to. Everything inside `<s:property>` tag `value` attribute will be evaluated. So if you have `myStuff` with accessors in action then following code will work.

```html
<button onclick="myJSFunction('<s:property value="myJavaModel.myJavaMethod(myStuff)" />')">Finalize</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store `myStuff` value in a hidden parameter in your JSP page.
Pass this hidden value to JS.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myStuffValue" value="<%=myModel.getMyMethodValue%>">
<input type="submit" onclick="play(<s:property value="myStuffValue"/>)">
```

Comment: You're setting the value to a hidden form field in the DOM and trying to access it with a JSP tag :( You could also just use `<s:set>`, but simply using OGNL the way it's intended is sufficient in this case.